# How to move data from listview and insert into database?

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, listview, insert

in my litte project, I have two listview and two db. First listview is fill from the first database table. the second is fill from the first selected item.

The two listboxes are built in same mode:

```
`name | surname | id`.
```

In the first listbox I have the list of all the users insert in the db

```
`Ale | Zucchelli | 5`
`Faby | Jake | 6`
`Alexa | Doctor | 7`
`Mattias | Rossi | 12`
```

When I select an element an click on the move button, the select item move to the second listbox.

```
 second listbox items

`Ale | Zucchelli | 5`
`Mattias | Rossi | 12`
```

When I click on Insert button, the items of the second listbox I must send it to second table of my db, but I must to register only the the id.

I have try this code:

private void btmconferma_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
    string idutente;
    //string idu_retrive = string.Empty;
    //object value = 0;
    idutente = user.Text;

    //string querysql2 = " INSERT INTO AMICIZIA (IdUtente1, [idamici]) VALUES ('" + idutente + "', '" + value + "')";
    //SqlConnection myconn = new SqlConnection(CnnStr);
    //SqlCommand mycmd = new SqlCommand(querysql2, myconn);
    foreach (ListViewItem l in listamicizie.Items)
    {
        string CnnStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["CnnStr"].ToString();
        SqlConnection myconn = new SqlConnection(CnnStr);
        myconn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into AMICIZIA (IdUtente1) values('" + idutente + "')", myconn);
        //SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("insert into AMICIZIA (idamici) values('" + l.SubItems["IdUtente"].ToString() + "')", myconn);
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("insert into AMICIZIA (idamici) values('" + listamicizie.Columns["IdUtente"].Text + "')", myconn);


        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myconn.Close();
    }


    this.Close();
}
```

The value of IdUtente is right, but the value of idamici is always zero.
How that i do?

Comment: Try something and post results before asking.

Comment: I have posted my code, and my result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQl should look like:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into AMICIZIA (IdUtente1) values('" + l.Text; + "')", myconn);
```

`ListViewItem l` is actual value in loop you created.

Comment: The code running. The last question, what I do to take only the value of the id column?

Comment: Explain what you mean please. Right question will help you understand it. What is your table structure? You wanna insert only part "12" from text string "Mattias | Rossi | 12" and like that?

Comment: Sorry for my explain, but I don't know English very well. My db table structure id IdUtente and Idamici. In Idamici I want insert only the third value of listview, in the Mattias Rossi case, in the Idamici column db appears only the 12

Comment: I solved my problem! :) Thanks so much @nuclaer sweet

the code is:

   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into AMICIZIA (IdUtente1, idamici) values('" + idutente + "', '" + l.SubItems[2].Text + "')", myconn);